# Ideals with finite number of zeros

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I tried a lot to understand the proof this theorem but I'm stuck how to show it is an isomorphism
"Let I be an ideal in $k[X1,...,Xn]$($k$ algebraically closed), and suppose $V(I)=\{P_1,...,P_N\}$ is finite. Let $O_i =O_{P_i}(A^n)$. Then there is a natural isomorphism of $k[X_1,...,X_n]/I$ with $\prod^N_{i=1}O_i/IO_i$."

Comment: What does 1Oi/IOi mean?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! I'm sorry, I couldn't understand what the last formula is really. Put your formulae between a pair of `$…$`.

Comment: I m studying algeraic curves by fulton....m stuck with the theorem in section 2.9 about the ideal with finite number of zeros that if  I be an ideal in k[X1,...,Xn] where k is algebraically closed and suppose V(I)={P1,...,PN} is finite. Let $O_i=O_{p_i} A^n$. Then there is a natural isomorphism of k[X1,...,Xn]/I with $\prod_i=1^N \frac {O_i}{I O_{p_i} A^n$